keep windows iconset from 100% display scale in higher scaling settings
I noticed that Icons get swapped at 100% display scale. Not that this is a pressing issue, but still somebody might know if there is some tweak in Windows to keep those Icons that are shown at 100% scale? At 100%, the icons are in their 2D representation, whereas at higher scaling they become 3D. The 2D ones look better.
100% scale

128% scale


Can you include screenshots of the different icons to illustrate the situation you are experiencing? What higher scalings? Please note that being very specific will help make your question clear.
